# uniqueness of solution of diff equation second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

In the case of a diff equation where $r_1=r_2$ the solution to $y''+py'+qy=0$ is

$y=Ce^{r_1 x}+Dxe^{r_1 x}$  (I)

In a proof I have for uniqueness of solution they start by defining $y=u e^{r_1 x}$ if $u''=0$ $ u=Cx+D$ and then $y=(Cx+D)e^{r_1 x}=ue^{r_1 x}$ But why does this show that only solution to y is(I). They also argue like this:

$y''+py'+qy=u''e^{r_1 x}+2r_1 u'e^{r_1 x}+ur_1^2 e^{r_1 x}+p(u'e^{r_1 x}+ur_1 e^{r_1 x}) +qe^{r_1 x}=[u''+(2r_1+p)u']e^{r_1 x}=0  (II)$

$r^2+pr+q=(r-r_1)^2=r^2-2r_1r+r_1^2$  $p=-2r_1$

which shows that   (II) gives $u''=0$ which is used above but that does not answer my question why using $y=ue^{r_1 x}$ shows that the only solution is (I)?

Answer (score 0):

On one hand the existence and uniqueness theorem for second order linear differential equation states:

If $p(t)$, $q(t)$, and $r(t)$ are continuous functions on an interval $[a,b]$, then the initial value problem

$$y'' + py' + qy  =  r \quad\quad y(t_0)  =  y_0,\quad y'(t_0)  =  y'_0$$

**has** a **unique** solution defined for all $t$ in $[a,b]$.

On the other hand, a second order linear ODE has two fundamental solutions (it can be put in the form of a $2 \times 2$ linear system). You have found the two fundamental solution, namely, $e^x$ and $xe^x$. Since the ODE is homogeneous, the general solution is a linear combination of your fundamental solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The idea in the proof is the following: Suppose you have any solution $y$. Then you can write the solution as $y(x) = u(x)e^{r_1x}$ for some differentiable function $u$ (why?). Through the calculations above, you obtain the condition $u'' = 0$. The solution to this differential equation *must* have the form $u(x) = C+Dx$ for some $C,D\in\mathbb{R}$, which means that your original solution $y$ *must* have the form $y(x) = (C+Dx)e^{r_1x}$ for some $C,D\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I dont get why you can write any solution as $u(x)e^{r_1 x}$?  :) :)

Comment: Let $u(x) = y(x)/e^{r_1x}$. Then $y(x) = u(x)e^{r_1x}$. (Now just check that $u$ is well-defined and differentiable...)

Comment: I have tried to look at this a bit more due to my struggle with the conotations of the proof. If we say $$u(x)=v(x)e^{-r_1 x}$$. so that  $$u(x)e^{r_1 x}=v(x)$$. I would see that we are dealing with an arbitrary solution v(x). Once we plug u into the equation: y’’+py’+q=0
We could obtain: $(u’’+(2r1+p)u’)e^{r1x}=0$   (V)
Then since r1=r2 are solution for y’’+py’+q=0, we could have p=-2r1 , plug this into equation (V):
We could have $$u’’e^{r_1 x}=0$$,since $e^{r_1 x}$ is not equal to 0,we could have u"=0
Thus, u=cx+d. And this is the important part for me in my next comment

Comment: Since v(x) is arbitrary we have proved that if we construct a completely arbitrary function $$y=ue^{r_1 x}$$ that can be any function we find that u''=0. Could this lead to check any solution of the diff equation?